# Determining Euclidean Distance in Polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, spatial-analyst

I would like to ask about how to create an euclidean distance analysis from a polygon shapefile.

I got a geology shapefile in which I want to create a "distance from geological boundary" analysis.

[image: Geology]
[image: Tools]

The idea is to create a distance from the geological boundary, I've done this several time with a polyline feature, but I've no idea how to do it with polygon.

Tools being used: Spatial Analyst>Distance>Euclidean Distance

The feature class: multi-polygon in one shapefile.

This is what I got when I run the euclidean distance with the polygon.

The analysis only returns the distance from the polygon perimeter

[image]

What I would like to see is the distance analysis from all the geological boundaries not just the perimeter.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: The process for a polygon should be the same as for a polyline.  Would you be able to edit your question to show the precise steps you are using, and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Thank you for replying @PolyGeo I put more information in the questions.

Comment: By precise steps I was expecting that you would include details like the tool(s) you are using, the parameters entered, what the input feature class(es) look like, the attributes in any output table(s), etc.  In this case the pictures of polygons do not seem to shine any light on the procedure you are using.

Comment: Thanks for replying @PolyGeo I put more information, basically what i what i got here is a shapefile of geological formation. From this data, I would like to create a distance from each geological boundary.

Comment: I don't have the licensing to be able to try and reproduce this so I will have to leave it to others.  As a new user of this site I recommend that you review [How to frame a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question).  I cannot undo the downvote that someone else put on this question but I will now upvote so that it gets back to a net 0.

Comment: Since you have been successful doing this for polylines, what's the matter with converting your polygons to polylines and proceeding as before?